# xpath query for javascript

Tags: xpath

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'http://www.vidok.co/s-static/v2/player-sp.swf',
    'file': 'http://www.vidok.co/cfs-ak-snc6/2012-12-17457.mp4',
    'image': '',
    'logo': 'www.vidok.co/s-static/rsrc.php/logo-player-sp.png',
    link': 'http://www.facefou.co/videos/watch-TqcLqlKBd2'
});
</script>
```

Hi I need the xpath query to get the "file : http://www.vidok.co/cfs-ak-snc6/2012-12-17457.mp4" from this script.

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
"substring-before(substring-after(/script, '&apos;file&apos;: '),
                    '&apos;image&apos;')"
```

And if you really want the "file : " at the beginning, use `concat('file : ', theaboveexpression)`.

But if you ask me, XPath is not the best tool for this job.

Better to use something like regular expressions to parse the Javascript.

Comment: Ok give me a exemple for regular expressions ?

Comment: @Benabra: `/'file':(.+)$/` would be the regexp. As to how you extract the file part, that depends on your processing environment.